# Rewrite Amazon s3 key

Tags: python, beginner, amazon-web-services

I've create a function that rewrites the key or "path" of an object in s3.

By default, Amazon Web Services Firehose writes to s3 in the format of `YYYY/MM/DD/HH/foo.json`. We have a AWS Lambda function listening for putObjects on `l1/source/event_type/fh/`, and when a new file is added to s3, the Lambda is invoked and the key or 'path' to that file is rewritten to a flat structure of `l1/source/event_type/daily/dt=YYYY-MM-DD/foo.json` - yes, I purposefully left-off the `fh` and `HH` paths.

**input** key: `l1/source/event_type/fh/YYYY/MM/DD/HH/foo.json`

**output** key: `l1/source/event_type/daily/dt=YYYY-MM-DD/foo.json`

```
def create_date_parition_from_key(key):
    '''creates new date parition prefix
    '''

    try:
        key_split = re.split(r'(/\d{4})', key)
        start_path = (key_split[0].split('/')[0], key_split[0].split('/')[1])
        remove_fh_path = '/'.join(start_path)
        default = key_split[2].split('/')
        year = key_split[1][1:]

        s3_prefix = remove_fh_path + '/'# /l1/foo/bar/baz/
        date_partion = ('daily/dt=' + 
                        '-'.join([year, default[1], default[2]]) + 
                        '/') # dt=YYYY-MM-DD/
        file_name = default[-1] # foo.json

        new_key = s3_prefix + date_partion + file_name

        print ('New partition key created: {}.'.format(new_key))

        return new_key
    except Exception as ex:
        print(ex)
        print('Error paritioning key {}.'.format(key))
        raise ex
```

I'm newer to python and am just looking for ways to improve my code as it seems fragile.

EDIT: The input key can vary in its number of paths:

- `l1/source/event_type/fh/YYYY/MM/DD/HH/foo.json`
- `l1/app/source/event_type/fh/YYYY/MM/DD/HH/foo.json`
- `l1/event_type/fh/YYYY/MM/DD/HH/foo.json`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Simplicity

[Tuple unpacking](http://openbookproject.net/thinkcs/python/english3e/tuples.html#tuple-assignment) and [`str.format`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) can simplify the function so much:

```
def create_date_parition_from_key(key):
    a,b,c,_,year, month, day, _, name = key.split('/')
    return "{}/{}/{}/daily/dt={}-{}-{}/{}".format(\
            a, b, c, year, month, day, name)
```

If input key can change in the number of paths:

```
def create_date_parition_from_key(key):
    *_, year, month, day, _, name = key.split('/')
    return "{}/daily/dt={}-{}-{}/{}".format(\
            key[:key.index("/fh/")], year, month, day, name)
```

#### Exception handling

```
try:
    # Things
except Exception as ex:
    print(ex)
    print('Error paritioning key {}.'.format(key))
    raise ex
```

This is against re-use. I cannot re-use this function because it inevitably prints to the console on error, I have no way of working around it throwing an exception with `try - except`.

This kind of error notification should be done in the `main` function that has exactly the job of communicating errors / successes of the other functions to the end user.

Finally `Exception` is too vague and too much code is inside the try block. Please reduce the code inside `try` as much as possible and specify a precise `Exception` kind.

I just removed all exception handling in my version as in my opinion it was just making the code worse while there was no need for it.

Comment: Thanks, however, I forgot to include that the 'path' can vary in the amount of folders it has prior to /fh. See EDIT in question.

Comment: @Blexy Ok, code edited for the new requirements. Please remember to add more examples / cite possible differences in input in your next question.

Comment: you bet. I'm trying to enter your code in python interpretor and I keep getting error when I enter-in *_ - invalid syntax.

Comment: @Blexy which Python version do you use?

Comment: I'm using 2.7.11

Comment: @Blexy My code works in 3.4.3 . In Python 2 use slicing `year, month, day, _, name = key[-5:]` instead of my variable length tuple unpacking. In the future also specify your python version with the appropriate tag in the question.